# How to calculate the standard error for multiple matrices in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, mean, standard-error

I want to calculate the standard error of multiple matrices concatenated into one:

```
cd C:\User\Aisk_000\Desktop\A\NC\Subjects\2014A\
A = dlmread('weights.txt');
cd ../3169A
B = dlmread('weights.txt');
cd ../3350A
C = dlmread('weights.txt');
cd ../3607A
D = dlmread('weights.txt');
cd ../4073A
E = dlmread('weights.txt');


%concatenate
x = cat(5,A,B,C,D,E)
y = mean(x,5)       %calculate the average
z = std( x ) / sqrt( length( x ))   %Calculate standard error
```

The output from `z` is a `5-D double`, same as the one for `x`. However, I realized that the system calculated the standard error of each matrix instead of the overall concatenated matrix. I know that it has something to do with the number "5", but I'm not sure where to put it in the code for `z`.

Comment: You probably wanted to  use `1` or `2`  instead of `5`.  See the doc of [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)

Comment: What the size/dimensionality of `A`, `B`, etc.?

Comment: @gnovice: the files are 16 by 16.

Comment: `std` also has to be computed along dimension 5. And instead of `length`, use `size(...,5)`.

Comment: @SardarUsama : I used 5 because I wanted to stack behind one another and find the average for that specific element/cell.

Comment: @CrisLuengo : I tried the code: `z = std( x,5 ) / sqrt( size( x,5 ))`, but I got an error from it. Where will I specify the `std` to calculate along dimesion 5?

Comment: See gnovice's answer below, he's written out what you need to do. You can also type `help std` in MATLAB and read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) isn't the number of matrices you are concatenating, it's the dimension along which you want to concatenate them. Since your matrices are all 2-D 16-by-16 matrices, it makes sense to concatenate them along the third dimension, stacking them into a 3-D matrix.

```
x = cat(3, A, B, C, D, E);
```

You can then use [`mean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) and [`std`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html), specifying `3` as the dimension along which to perform the calculation:

```
y = mean(x, 3);                      % Mean along dimension 3
z = std(x, 0, 3)./sqrt(size(x, 3));  % Standard error along dimension 3
```

Comment: I see. I misunderstood `cat` to begin with, and the code is now able to run smoothly with what I want now. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Aiskya: Happy to help!